# OG subscription problem

Tags: organic-groups

My users can only become activated in only one group after subscription. I have mentioned them to subscribe without approval. But, when each of them subscribe in one group, can not see the link of subscribing for other groups.

So, I have also activated the:

Organic groups access control
Organic groups field access

And I am using the last version of OG beside drupal 7. And, I have also activated the private/public option for groups.

Please help me.

Comment: It's solved! I had to enable the following permission for my users:

"Administer Organic groups permissions".

I still don't know why this permission should be activated for them.

Comment: However it's not the proper solution!!!!